# How to display my inputted data after clicking "submit" button?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

i'm really sorry if im asking too dumb question, im really not a pro in programming, but im trying hard. So here is my problem, i created these 2 layouts.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#E0E0E0" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:ems="14"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myRadioGroup"
     android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
     android:text="Gender:"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <RadioGroup
     android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
     android:checkedButton="@+id/sound" >

     <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/sound"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Male" />

     <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/vibration"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Female" />
 </RadioGroup>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_below="@+id/myRadioGroup"
     android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
     android:text="Known Computer Languages:"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
     android:text="C#" />

 <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox1"
     android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
     android:text="C++" />

 <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox2"
     android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
     android:text="Java" />

 <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox3"
     android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
     android:text="JavaScript" />

 <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox1"
     android:text="Python" />

 <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox2"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox2"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox5"
     android:text="Ruby" />

 <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox3"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox3"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox6"
     android:text="PHP" />

 <CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox7"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox4"
     android:text="SQL" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
     android:text="Next Page" />
```

and here is the other one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:background="#E0E0E0">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="How long have you been learning programming?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" >

</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="What programming language are you most interested in?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Programming language you find easy"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Programming language you find difficult"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:ems="10" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:text="Submit" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Please toggle on the button if you want to view the inputs after submission, toggle off if not."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

So my problem is, in the first layout, i want to be able to after i click next, i should be able to move to the next layout. (Haven't done it yet, since i really do not know how, tried to follow some youtube videos but i really cannot understand them) Assuming i connected the 2 layouts, and i move on to the next layout. Which contains a "submit" button at the end, i want to be able to let the user choose if he/she wants to immediately display the data they input into the layout 1 and 2. I put a toggle button in layout 2, which means that, if the toggle button is "on" before clicking submit, it should immediately show all the data they inputted including the questions. If they toggle the toggle button off before clicking submit, it should only display a small text notification on the bottom side something like, "form successfully submitted".

Im really really sorry if im asking this alot of questions and a wall of text. My teacher just expects too much of me, and im trying my best. (well, maybe not "too much" im might be just really just slow learner in programming) Thank you all. Im using eclipse by the way..

Comment: Post your activity's source code.

Comment: You should start reading `Intents (which is useful to move between activity)`, `Button listener` & `toggle` topics to do this. You can start right from [here](http://developer.android.com). E'though we help, if you make a single mistake like missing dots, you won't understand how to debug. Put some efforts. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Create a class ModelPerson to hold the values a person

```
public class ModelPerson {
        String name = null;
        String gender = null; //insert the radio button value into this
        //
        //write getter and setter methods for above variables
        }
```

In Activity 1: Inside submit button clickListener(), start new intent , put values into it

```
ModelPerson  personObj  = new ModelPerson();
personObj.setName(editText1.getText.getString);
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,
                    Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("PersonsDetails", personObj)
            startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity 2: Inside onCreate() get the intent values using getExtra() method and retrieve the values from the Model person object.